# Transitioning Animation, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning dismiss error?

Tags: ios, swift

`Xcode 12.5.1` with `Swift version 5.4.2`

I use the following code to do Transitioning Animation for viewController dismissing

```
enum PresentingDirection{
    case top, right, left, bottom
    
    var bounds: CGRect{
        UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
    
    func offsetF(withFrame viewFrame: CGRect) -> CGRect{
        let h = bounds.size.height
        let w = bounds.size.width
        switch self {
        case .top:
            return viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -h)
        case .bottom:
            return viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: h)
        case .left:
            return viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: -w, dy: 0)
            
        case .right:
            return viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: w, dy: 0)
            
        }
        
    }
}


class CustomDismissController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning{
    
    
    fileprivate var presentingDirection: PresentingDirection
    
    
    init(direction orientation: PresentingDirection) {
        presentingDirection = orientation
    }
    
    
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }
    
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        
        guard let fromCtrl = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
              let toCtrl = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to), let toView = toCtrl.view else{
            return
        }
        
        let finalCtrlFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromCtrl)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        fromCtrl.view.alpha = 0.5
        toView.frame = presentingDirection.offsetF(withFrame: finalCtrlFrame)
    

        containerView.bringSubviewToFront(toView)
  
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            toView.frame = finalCtrlFrame
       
        } completion: { _ in
            let success = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the the best I can do.

I want the effect `fromCtrl.view.alpha = 1`

As I tested, `fromCtrl.view.alpha = 0.5`  is very important.

Without it, the second view controller stays , I can not see the first view controller's frame animation

**It seems like to be an iOS bug**

Any good idea?

I also tried `snapshotView`

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        
        guard let fromCtrl = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
              let toCtrl = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to), let toView = toCtrl.view, let snapshot = fromCtrl.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false) else{
            return
        }
        
        let finalCtrlFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromCtrl)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        fromCtrl.view.isHidden = true
        snapshot.frame = finalCtrlFrame
        containerView.addSubview(snapshot)
        toView.frame = presentingDirection.offsetF(withFrame: finalCtrlFrame)
    

        containerView.bringSubviewToFront(toView)
  
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            toView.frame = finalCtrlFrame
       
        } completion: { _ in
            let success = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }

    }
```

Not good.

[full code in github](https://github.com/coyingcat/TransitionsLearn/tree/main/one)

Answer (score 1):

I solved.

The animation is the snapshot's thing.

Just layout to viewController's frame properly.

```
 func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        
        guard let fromCtrl = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
              let toCtrl = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to), let toView = toCtrl.view, let snapshot = toView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) else{
            return
        }
        
        let finalCtrlFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromCtrl)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        snapshot.frame =
            presentingDirection.offsetF(withFrame: finalCtrlFrame)
        
        containerView.addSubview(snapshot)
        containerView.bringSubviewToFront(toView)
        toView.frame = finalCtrlFrame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveLinear) {
            snapshot.frame = finalCtrlFrame
        } completion: { _ in
            snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            
            let success = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }
    }
```

Failed to try to put snapshot under  `toView`